# THEANO_FLAGS: Command not found

Tags: python, theano

My settings of `.theanorc` file is `device = gpu0`, but I want to know if I can run one program with `gpu0`, and run another with `gpu1`, I tried `THEANO_FLAGS='device=gpu1' python myscript.py` but it raised `THEANO_FLAGS: Command not found.`

Answer (score 1):

just add these 2 lines in the script:

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "device=gpu1"
```

Answer (score 0):

`THEANO_FLAGS='device=gpu1' python myscript.py` is working for me. 
Are you sure you have no space character after `THEANO_FLAGS`, like this: `THEANO_FLAGS ='device=gpu1' python myscript.py`.
This would raise the `THEANO_FLAGS: Command not found`